# Adding methods and call to's

Tags: java, methods

In the following code I'm attempting to insert methods and call to's that will make the program operate.  I've attempted to place the first method into the program.

```
public class My_Geometry {

    public static void printMenu() {
        System.out.println("This is a geometry calculator, Choose what you would like to calculate: ");
        System.out.println("1) Find the area of a rectangle");
        System.out.println("2) Find the perimeter of a rectangle");
        System.out.println("3) Find the perimeter of a triangle");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int choice;   //the user's choice
        double value;  //the value returned from the method
        char letter;  //the Y or N from the user's decision to exit
        double radius;  //the radius of the circle
        double length;  //the length of the rectangle
        double width;  //the width of the rectangle
        double height;  //the height of the triangle
        double base;  //the base of the triangle
        double side1;  //the first side of the triangle
        double side2;  //the second side of the triangle
        double side3;  //the third side of the triangle

//create a scanner object to read from the keyboard
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

//do loop was chose to allow the menu to be displayed first
        letter = 'N';
        while (letter != 'Y' && letter != 'y') {

            printMenu();

            choice = keyboard.nextInt();
            value = 0.0;

            switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.print("Enter the length of the rectangle:  ");
                    length = keyboard.nextDouble();
                    System.out.print("Enter the width of the rectangle:  ");
                    width = keyboard.nextDouble();
                    rectangleArea();
                    System.out.println("The area of the rectangle is " + value);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.print("Enter the length of the rectangle:  ");
                    length = keyboard.nextDouble();
                    System.out.print("Enter the width of the rectangle:  ");
                    width = keyboard.nextDouble();
                    // add call to rectanglePerimeter method here
                    System.out.println("The perimeter of the rectangle is " + value);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.print("Enter the length of side 1 of the triangle:  ");
                    side1 = keyboard.nextDouble();
                    System.out.print("Enter the length of side 2 of the triangle:  ");
                    side2 = keyboard.nextDouble();
                    System.out.print("Enter the length of side 3 of the triangle:  ");
                    side3 = keyboard.nextDouble();
                    // add call to trianglePerimeter method here
                    System.out.println("The perimeter of the triangle is " + value);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("You did not enter a valid choice.");
            }
            keyboard.nextLine(); //consumes the new line character after the number
            System.out.println("Do you want to exit the program (Y/N)?:  ");
            String answer = keyboard.nextLine();
            letter = answer.charAt(0);
        }
    }

}
public static void rectangleArea() {
        value = length * width;
}
// add call to rectanglePerimeter method here
// add call to trianglePerimeter method here
```

`public static rectangleArea(){
value = length * width;}`
is the method that I am attempting to insert into the program.

This is the location that I was asked to place it, but I have no idea if it is written correctly or not.  My call to this method is `rectangleArea()` which is placed in the middle of the code and I believe that is the correct way to call to this method.  I just don't know what is wrong with the method itself or what the proper way to write it would be.

Comment: Based on you code, you are being asked to add the methods outside of the class, this can't be done in Java, you may need to seek more clarification from the person who set you the assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rectangleArea` has no return type.  If it returns nothing then it should be declared with `void`

For example...

```
public static void rectangleArea(){
```

The method is also outside of the class, which is illegal in Java.  You need to move it up before the last `}`

`value`, `width` and `length` have no context within the method, as these are declared as local variables within `main`.

You will probably need to pass `length` and `width` to the method and return the `value`, for example...

```
public static double rectangleArea(double length, double width) {
    return length * width;
}
```

**Updated...**

Calling the method requires three things.  It requires you to pass the `length` and `width` to the method and assign the return value back to a variable (assuming you're interested in the return result)...

For example...

```
value = rectangleArea(length, width);
```

Comment: Alright.  So I need to include the types of variables in the method.  How would I call to the method though?  Using rectangleArea(); seems to gives me an error stating that "double, double is required" and that it "cannot be applied to given types"

Comment: I see now.  This makes much more sense to me.  You've really helped with my understanding of methods.  I was very lost before this.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: add a `void` for return type declaration

```
public static void rectangleArea(){
    value = length * width;
}
```

and promote your variables to fields of the class (by moving out of the main method).

Option 2: Hand over your operands to your computation methods, let them return the computed value and assign the returned value to a local variable of your `main` method:

```
public static double rectangleArea(double lenght, double width){
    return length * width;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // ..

    double area = rectangleArea(l, w);
    System.out.println("Area: " + area);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem of scoping your variables. You have declared variables inside your main method so they are visible only there. Format your code with correct indentation and I think that will help. You can think of each { } defining a scope.

Answer (score 0):

The variables length and width are in the scope of the main method.
You can declare outside the method the length width and value variables and make them static, or you can pass the values as method parameters and return the calculated value.
If you choose the first suggested solution you must declare void as the type of the method.